# How to know the field is BINARY type in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, c, swift

I have several MySQL tables with BINARY filed type, mostly for storing different UUIDs (16 bytes length).
I'm querying the tables from Swift, the problem is the filed gets converted to String instead of expected UInt8 array.

I was looking at the underlying MySQL C library and the value for MYSQL_BIND.buffer_type is actually MYSQL_TYPE_VAR_STRING, that is why Swift wrapper converts it to String.

Is there a way to know that the field type is actually BINARY from the result?

Comment: *Is there a way to know that the field type is actually BINARY from the result?* No way. You may look for the actual column datatype by quering [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/columns-table.html) system view. Then you may use proper built-in functions for to convert the value to the format which you need in the query.

Comment: I ended up adding extra info to the function that fetches fields, eg. which columns are BINARY.